# My huawei phone is not receiving text messages?

Tags: sms

My huawei Y3II was working fine and receiving messages without any problem. But, one day I realized that one or two weeks have been passed and I did not got any text message. Then I checked by sending message from another phone but, I did not received. I have not done anything with my phone then, what could be the problem.

Comment: Don't know why but this may help 1. Restart the device 2 Clear  cache and data of the Messaging app. If this doesn't help try a different messaging app

Comment: How can I clear cache of my messaging app. With what name would I find my messaging app in all apps.

Comment: Huawei options are different but from Settings > Apps> Manage or show system apps > messaging> storage you should find clear cache and clear data .  clear cache and if it doesn't help clear data (you would lose existing SMS so back them up by using any app from Play store that does this) If you can't locate try an [app like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.classiccache) but you should be able to find it with some search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Factory Reset** has solved my problem. This also solved my second problem which was automatically turning off sometimes and then showing 'Starting apps' and taking too much time on it.

->  First of all I saved all my data to sd card and then switched off the phone and took out my sd card.

-> Then I reached to options by pressing power button and volume up button and releasing power button when logo is shown while continuing pressing volume up button.

-> Then I selected **wipe data/factory reset** option. It took just a few seconds to complete factory reset and then I rebooted the phone.

Reference : https://drfone.wondershare.com/reset-android/wipe-data-factory-reset.html